# Regex for multiline text area

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to validate text area. Format should be us following:

```
Text description: ${VARIABLE_NAME} \n
Text description: ${VARIABLE_NAME}
```

Rules:

1. Text description can contain a-zA-Z0-9 spaces and "_"
2. Text description need to be followed ":"
3. ":" can be followed with no or one space
4. after ": " string need to start with "${"
5. "VARIABLE_NAME" can contain only A-Z and "_"
6. "VARIABLE_NAME" and line need to finish with "}"

Text can have multiple lines, every line need to follow all 6 rules.

For now i have this regex `const regex = new RegExp('[\\w+]:\\$\\{[A-Z]+}$', 'gs');`
Just not sure how to handle multiple lines.

Comment: The rules don't seem to mention a space before the newline.

Comment: So you want to allow the string to end with a newline, it should be one of the explicit rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirements can be matched as follows:

1. → <kbd>`[\w ]+`</kbd> 2. → <kbd>:</kbd> 3. →  <kbd>?</kbd> 4. → <kbd>\$\{</kbd> 5. → <kbd>[A-Z_]+</kbd> 6. → <kbd>}</kbd>

Put into a  `(?:` [non capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions) `(?:\n|$))` `+` for [one or more](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) lines.

```
^(?:[\w ]+: ?\$\{[A-Z_]+}(?:\n|$))+$
```

See [this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Uu3f8k/1) or a [JS demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##jY/BasJAFEX3@Yq3CEyGqNmWiJUpZFFou5DShY5KSB8hJbwJM8@YYv32OImt4K7by@Wce7/yNneFrRqetg99XxhyDBZL7GAByS5apht9hG2cwlKH@rRR0/V@G599ruknlDIOk3kQJAmomtFSzlWL4L6J8w4OrqISVlhmXQMj2R4KNnao34sIj7@9SFydN6m33mv/vEIGQY0MnuoJ4h07hk@8fqkMpaDD04daPaunl2z/pl6zs6Z/lIS/M4wzNc5qU0YePxGaFo9iMq6dMToeUin7/gI) (use [`\r?\n`](https://regex101.com/r/zrV9rF/1) for [CRLF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CRLF?retiredLocale=de) support)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
/^[\w ]+:[^\S\r\n]?\${[A-Z_]+}(?:\r?\n[\w ]+:[^\S\r\n]?\${[A-Z_]+})*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z0hthv/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[\w ]+` - one or more alphanumeric/underscore/space chars
- `:` - a colon
- `[^\S\r\n]?` - an optional horizontal whitespace
- `\${` - a `${` string
- `[A-Z_]+` - one or more uppercase ASCII letters or underscores
- `}` - a `}` char
- `(?:\r?\n[\w ]+:[^\S\r\n]?\${[A-Z_]+})*` - zero or more repetitions of the CRLF or LF line ending sequence followed with the above explained pattern
- `$` - end of string.